# Multiple OAuth authorized connections from a single user ID to an application

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Is it possible to have multiple concurrent OAuth authorized connections from a single user ID to a single application?

ex. User ID abc@company.com authorizes access to application XYZ (via Step 2 of https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere). The action is performed again where the user authorizes access to application XYZ. Both tokens captured remain valid for use in the future.

Currently, a subsequent OAuth authorization invalidates the token from a previous OAuth authorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection is between the data in the cloud (realm) and the application, and there can only be one per realm. If the same user tries to authorize, the Company will not show up in the selection screen as it has already been chosen.

If another user from the same company tries to do it they will get an error that the company is already connected.

It's not a technical limitation its how the connections are billed. You would not want multiple connections to the same realm from a billing pov.

If you can tell me what your use case is, I can point you in the right direction as I am not sure why you would want multiple Oauth connections to the same data set.

thanks
Jarred

Comment: small correction.  the company does show; but, the UI wil indicate that the company has an existing OAuth token for that app/user combination.  if the user selects the same company, a new OAuth verifier is issued and the previously issued OAuth token is deactivated.